# Tagged URL resulting in questions with spurious tags

Tags: support, bug, tags, hyperlinks

I have a bookmark with the following URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript+or+vba+or+excel-vba+or+word-vba+or+outlook-vba+or+.net+or+.net-2.0+or+.net-3.5+or+.net-4.0+or+.net-4.5+or+.net-4.5.1+or+.net-4.5.2+or+vb.net+or+vb.net-2010+or+vb.net-designer+or+c#-to-vb.net+or+vb.net-to-c#+or+c#+or+c#-2.0+or+c#-3.0+or+c#-4.0+or+visual-studio+or+visual-studio-2005+or+visual-studio-2008+or+visual-studio-2010+or+visual-studio-2010-sp1+or+visual-studio-2013+or+winforms+or+sql+or+tsql+or+sql-server+or+sql-server-2000+or+sql-server-2005+or+sql-server-2008+or+sql-server-2008-r2+or+sql-server-2012+or+design-patterns+or+infragistics+or+redemption+or+outlook-redemption?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=100
```

Among the other questions I'm seeing which all have at least one of the above tags, I'm getting questions **that only have tags like `c` and `c++` and no others**.  Why?

FYI, I'm using Firefox, though I don't know how that could possibly matter.

Comment: Works for me: 500k questions

Comment: @juergend -- Here's an example which shows up in the top 6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843557/what-impact-has-c-had-on-c

Comment: I'm seeing a variety of questions from all the different tags in your list.

Comment: @animuson -- Correct, but my list doesn't include `c` and `c++`, so why would it return questions that **only** have those tags, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843557/what-impact-has-c-had-on-c?

Comment: @animuson -- I've updated my question to clarify my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what is happening. Your search query is too long, so it's cutting it off at the character limit.

Your URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript+or+vba+or+excel-vba+or+word-vba+or+outlook-vba+or+.net+or+.net-2.0+or+.net-3.5+or+.net-4.0+or+.net-4.5+or+.net-4.5.1+or+.net-4.5.2+or+vb.net+or+vb.net-2010+or+vb.net-designer+or+c#-to-vb.net+or+vb.net-to-c#+or+c#+or+c#-2.0+or+c#-3.0+or+c#-4.0+or+visual-studio+or+visual-studio-2005+or+visual-studio-2008+or+visual-studio-2010+or+visual-studio-2010-sp1+or+visual-studio-2013+or+winforms+or+sql+or+tsql+or+sql-server+or+sql-server-2000+or+sql-server-2005+or+sql-server-2008+or+sql-server-2008-r2+or+sql-server-2012+or+design-patterns+or+infragistics+or+redemption+or+outlook-redemption
```

Becomes:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript+or+vba+or+excel-vba+or+word-vba+or+outlook-vba+or+.net+or+.net-2.0+or+.net-3.5+or+.net-4.0+or+.net-4.5+or+.net-4.5.1+or+.net-4.5.2+or+vb.net+or+vb.net-2010+or+vb.net-designer+or+c#-to-vb.net+or+vb.net-to-c#+or+c#+or+c#-2.0+or+c#-3.0+or+c#-4.0+or+visual-studio+or+visual-studio-2005+or+visual-studio-2008+or+visual-studio-2010+or+visual-studio-2010-sp1+or+visual-studio-2013+or+winforms+or+sql+or+tsql+or+sql-server+or+sql-server-2000+or+sql-server-2005+or+sql-server-2008+or+sql-server-2008-r2+or+sql-server-2012+or+design-patterns+or+infragistics+or+redemption+or+outlook-redemption
```

Where it is cutting off at the [c#-to-vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-to-vb.net) tag and only taking the "c" character at the beginning of it, interpreting it as a search for the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag.

Answer (score 3):

After much trial and error, I realized the answer was a lot more simple than "the URL is too long".  The problem was that my URL contained the `#` character (as in `c#-to-vb.net`), which is obviously a special character in a URL.

The solution is to use the proper URL-encoded tags, e.g. `c%23-to-vb.net`.